# PlaceMarker, cannot convert value of type:

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

i'm creating this class

```
import UIKit
import GooglePlaces
import GoogleMaps

class PlaceMarker: GMSMarker {
    let place: GMSPlace


    init(place: GMSPlace) {
        self.place = place
        super.init()

        position = place.coordinate
        icon = UIImage(named: place.types+"_pin")
        groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
        appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
    }
}
```

using for the PlaceMarker, but in the line

```
icon = UIImage(named: place.types+"_pin")
```

i take to `_pin` the error `Cannot convert value of type 'Never' to expected argument type 'String'` , how can i adjust it? I tried to change `_pin` with `place.name` or `String()` but the issue is the same

Comment: try with this `"\(place.types)_pin"`

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani Make this an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try with this** `"\(place.types)_pin"`

Comment: Happy to help :)